# Mac OS FullScreenUtility with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, macos-sierra

So, I want to disable the Mac OS fullscreen option (the maximize button doubles as both fullscreen and maximize), and I found a way to edit it, take a look:

```
com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities.setWindowCanFullScreen(Window, boolean);
```

Problem is, the method requires that I input an AWT Window. I was wondering if any of you guys know ways to use JavaFX windows with this? Or perhaps a method to get an AWT Window from a JavaFX Stage/Scene/Window?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an action listener it would look something like

```
stage.fullScreenProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> stage.setFullScreen(false));
```

Comment: Yeah, that didn't help. My program froze and I had to force quit the entire JVM and Eclipse